# Change file name before upload to server in ckeditor dotnetnuke

Tags: c#, file-upload, ckeditor, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I base on html module DNN and created new one for my module myshelf. This is a instance of new ckeditor i created [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FgZ7.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyTTA.png) [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzgyC.png) **

I searched from internet and they told put this url to upload image. And I uploaded [Image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd1CW.png)

The problem is if multiple users upload file but same name. The ckeditor justs change the second file's name with _1 in tail of file's name. And then the third file they override the second, they don't make second , third like _2 , _3, ...

I could't find the code behind of this file /Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/DNNConnect.CKE/Browser/Browser.aspx in this this upload url. So i couldn't change file's name

```
filebrowserUploadUrl: '/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/DNNConnect.CKE/Browser/Browser.aspx?Command=FileUpload&tabid=' + tabid + '&PortalID=' + portalid + '&mid=' + moduleid + '&ckid=' + ckid + '&mode=Portal&lang=' + language + '',
```

Doesn't anyone know where the code behind upload file or any solution change file's name before upload in tab upload of ckeditor in DNN.

Comment: I think this is the source https://github.com/DNN-Connect/CKEditorProvider

Comment: File naming should happen under ProcessImage > GenerateName

Answer (score 0):

Thanks erw13n ! Finnally I found the code behind your link [github.com/DNN-Connect/CKEditorProvider](http://github.com/DNN-Connect/CKEditorProvider).

I just add a line to generate new filename in Browser.aspx.cs file then build to new file .dll and copy to source web ! Thank you so much !

Comment: You should start a pull request. Otherwise chances are high that you will lose your changes with the next upgrade.